# How to output different command in Discord.js and .JSON using else if structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to output a different command based on what an element in the JSON array is equal to. So if PerkData.perks[i].character = "Survivor", it would output "survEmbed". Here is what I've tried that gives me an error when I try to execute a command that has "Survivor" as the character element:

**perk.js:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const PerkData = require('./perk.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'perk',
    args: true,
    execute(message, args) {
        for (let i = 0; i < PerkData.perks.length; i++) {
            if (PerkData.perks[i].id.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLowerCase()) {
                const perkEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                .setColor('#D41C1C')
                .setTitle('__**' + PerkData.perks[i].name + '**__')
                .setURL(PerkData.perks[i].url)
                .setThumbnail(PerkData.perks[i].gif)
                .setDescription('A teachable unique [' + PerkData.perks[i].character + '](' + PerkData.perks[i].characterURL + ') Perk <:Icon_Perk:815066150865469481>. It can be unlocked for all other characters from Level ' + PerkData.perks[i].lvl + ' onwards:')
                .addField('__Description__', PerkData.perks[i].description, false)

                message.channel.send(perkEmbed)
            }
            else if (PerkData.perks[i].id.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLowerCase() && PerkData.perks[i].character === 'Survivor') {
                const survEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                .setColor('#D41C1C')
                .setTitle('__**' + PerkData.perks[i].name + '**__')
                .setDescription(PerkData.perks[i].name + 'is a general ' + PerkData.perks[i].character + ' Perk <:Icon_Perk:815066150865469481>.')

                message.channel.send(survEmbed)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**perk.json:**

```
{
    "perks": [
        {
            "id": "alert",
            "name": "Alert",
            "url": "",
            "gif": "",
            "character": "Feng Min",
            "characterURL": "",
            "lvl": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "spine-chill",
            "name": "",
            "url": "",
            "gif": "",
            "character": "Survivor",
            "lvl": "",
            "description": ""
        }
}
```

(My JSON file is much larger than that but I didn't include the whole thing.)

Answer (score 1):

You should include what error you're getting.

You can use a `Map()` to store data

`key` -> character/id from Perk

`value` -> MessageEmbed()

unfortunately, there is no short way if you want different style and data in different embeds

```js
// declare map to store all embeds
const embedMap = new Map();

// make embed to store
const survEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#D41C1C')
    .setTitle('__**' + PerkData.perks[0].name + '**__')
    .setDescription(PerkData.perks[0].name + 'is a general ' + PerkData.perks[0].character + ' Perk <:Icon_Perk:815066150865469481>.')

// store in Map
embedMap.set("survivor", survEmbed);

// Repeat the same process for each perk...

// get embed corresponding to args[0] and send it
return message.channel.send(embedMap.get(args[0].toLowerCase()));
```

**OR** if you want same structure and forrmat for each embed it'll be easier

```js
// declare map to store all embeds
const embedMap = new Map();

// loop though each perk
PerkData.perks.forEach(perk => {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#D41C1C')
        .setTitle('__**' + perk.name + '**__')
        // use description field in your perk to get this structure
        .setDescription(perk.description)

    // set embed to Map, considering you want perk.character to be same as arg[0]
    embedMap.set(perk.character.toLowerCase(), embed);
});

// send embed to cmd response
return message.channel.send(embedMap.get(args[0].toLowerCase()));
```